# Fetch facebook friends using facebook sdk 4.1 for android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am developing an android app in which I want to fetch all the friends which are using the same app, using **facebook sdk 4.1** , I tried to find latest tutorials but didn't find anyone... I tried to use GraphRequestBatch but onCompleted is never called, please help!!

```
package com.miivideos;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.example.miivideos.R;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphRequestBatch;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;

public class FriendList extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "FriendList";
    public static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions", "email", "user_location","user_friends");
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    AccessToken accesstoken=AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.friend_list);
        android.app.ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.green));
        ab.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        new GetFriendList().execute();

    }

    class GetFriendList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog pdig = new ProgressDialog(FriendList.this);
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Working in background...");
            //LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(FriendList.this, Arrays.asList("user_friends"));
            //Log.i(TAG,"Having token for: "+String.valueOf(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions()));

            GraphRequestBatch batch = new GraphRequestBatch(
                    GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest(accesstoken,
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONArrayCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONArray jarray,
                                        GraphResponse response) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "onCompleted: jsonArray "
                                            + jarray);
                                    Log.i(TAG, "onCompleted: response "
                                            + response);
                                    Toast.makeText(FriendList.this, "result:"+jarray.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }));
            batch.addCallback(new GraphRequestBatch.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onBatchCompleted(GraphRequestBatch batch) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onbatchCompleted: jsonArray "
                            + batch);

                }
            });
            batch.executeAsync();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (pdig.isShowing())
                pdig.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pdig.setTitle("Fetching");
            pdig.setMessage("Fetching facebook friends...");
            //pdig.show();
            Log.i(TAG, "Starting...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }


    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I m using the above piece of code.. exactly the same, but on Completed is never called,,, any idea why ?

Comment: check your permissions in app settings, from your facbook account, if permission is not granted to see friend list etc , then that method will fail to execute and hence will never complete....

Answer (score 2):

This simply should work.

And, as mentioned, only shared friends are returned, plus the total count of your friends.

```
private void getFriends() {
    AccessToken accesstoken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest(accesstoken,
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONArrayCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONArray jsonArray, GraphResponse response) {
                    System.out.println("jsonArray: " + jsonArray);
                    System.out.println("GraphResponse: " + response);
                }
            }).executeAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found how to do this, but in sdk 4.1.0 facebook will only provide friends that are using your app or common app between users, not all the friend list!

```
GraphRequestBatch batch = new GraphRequestBatch(GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest(
                        accesstoken,
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONArrayCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONArray jsonArray, GraphResponse response) {
                                System.out.println("jsonArray: "+jsonArray);
                                System.out.println("GraphResponse: "+response);
                                try {
                                    ArrayList<Friend_List_Load> item_details = new ArrayList<Friend_List_Load>();
                                    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                                        JSONObject c=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                        System.out.println("id: "+c.getString(PROFILE_ID));
                                        System.out.println("name: "+c.getString(NAME));
                                        FriendListAdapter frndadapter=new FriendListAdapter(FriendList.this,item_details);
                                        item_details.add(new Friend_List_Load(c.getString(NAME),c.getString(PROFILE_ID)));
                                        lv_friends.setAdapter(frndadapter);
                                    }                   
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        }),
                        GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accesstoken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                System.out.println("meJSONObject: "+object);
                                System.out.println("meGraphResponse: "+response);

                            }
                        })
        );
        batch.addCallback(new GraphRequestBatch.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onBatchCompleted(GraphRequestBatch graphRequests) {
                //Log.i(TAG, "onCompleted: graphRequests "+ graphRequests);
            }
        });
        batch.executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check updated document and new changes for graph api of facebook android sdk 4.x [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x)

Hope it will be helpful.